# Failed to use Chart.js using Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, charts, chart.js

Hello im trying to use one of the Charts from http://www.chartjs.org but i cant make it works.. i installed npm install chart.js --save as documentation requires and the use this code to creat the chart.

**.TS**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent  {

constructor(){

var lineChartData: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
var lineChartLabels: string[] = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];

var  lineChartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    animation: false,
     beginAtZero:true

  };
var lineChartColors: Array<any> = [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,0.8)'
    },
    { // dark grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,1)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,0.8)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,0.8)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,0.8)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,0.8)'
    }    
  ];

  var lineChartLegend: boolean = true;
  var lineChartType: string = 'line';


}

}
```

**.HTML**

```
    <script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>

<canvas baseChart height="200"
        [datasets]="lineChartData"
        [labels]="lineChartLabels"
        [options]="lineChartOptions"
        [colors]="lineChartColors"
        [legend]="lineChartLegend"
        [chartType]="lineChartType"
  ></canvas>
```

**.MODULE**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Updated code, the page is blank, have no errors in console but this message :

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart.js needs to be wrapped so it will work with typescript. Using `import {chart} from 'chart.js';` won't work. Try a different npm library like this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts

I've had success with it. Should fix your issue.

You won't need to import chart at all.

Just include your cart in your html. Something like this:

```
 <canvas baseChart height="200"
        [datasets]="lineChartData"
        [labels]="lineChartLabels"
        [options]="lineChartOptions"
        [colors]="lineChartColors"
        [legend]="lineChartLegend"
        [chartType]="lineChartType"
  ></canvas>
```

Then access it in your component. Something like this:

```
lineChartData: Array<any>;
lineChartLabels: string[] = [..data..    
  ];

  lineChartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    animation: false,

  };
  lineChartColors: Array<any> = [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,0.8)'
    },
    { // dark grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,1)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,0.8)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,0.8)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,0.8)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,0.8)'
    }    
  ];

  lineChartLegend: boolean = true;
  lineChartType: string = 'line';
```

Comment: Hi, i added import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts'; to the app module , but in the component this makes an error :


this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, { 

It says cannot find name Chart.

Comment: Are you still importing "chart" in the component. You don't need to do this.

Comment: no im not... i will upload new code for you, check.

Comment: Get rid of the new chart line and include the baseChart directive in the html file. Oh and you need to tell the canvas file which variable it should be using. See the example I included in my revised answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151917/discussion-between-ixam-deirf-and-notmfb).